# How does this imply "the unit balls completely determine the metric space structure"?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space. Suppose you know that $$B[x,r] = x + rB[0,1]\qquad\text{and}\qquad B(x,r) = x + rB(0,1)$$

where $B[x,r]$ and $B(x,r)$ are respectively the closed and open balls in $X$. How does it then follow that you can state that "the unit balls completely determine the metric space structure"?

Thanks.

Comment: What do the notations $rB(0,1)$ and $rB[0,1]$ ***mean*** in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: @ZevChonoles X is also a vector space. So rB(0,1):= {rb : b in B(0,1)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only additional structure a metric space has beyond its topology is the metric (which must either be consistent with existing topology, or induces a topology depending on how you look at it). We could define a metric space by explicitly defining the metric, or we we could simply define what all of the balls are (i.e., a basis for topology), and then we arrive at a metric consistent with this topology by defining
$$d(x,y)=\inf \{r:y\in B[x,r]\}.$$
If this definition of metric fails to meet any of the metric space axioms, in particular if
$$d(y,x)=\inf \{r:x\in B[y,r]\}\neq d(x,y),$$
then the topology induced by this basis is not metrizable. Otherwise, the basis describes a unique metric on the space.

Based on the fact that $X$ is a vector space, and the construction given, it shouldn't be too difficult to prove that $\{B[x,r]:x\in X,r\in\mathbb R^+\}$ induces a metric that is consistent with metric space axioms.